# Shell: command with timeout, get output

Tags: shell, timeout, output

The problem is I want to get some info from a file 'Institution' within un archive tar file (which is big and take time to unzip), so I try the command like this:

```
timeout 0.5s awk '/FormattedDescription/{getline;print}' archivage001.1.tar
```

0.5 second is enough, so it is much more faster...

The problem is when I execute the command directly in a cygwin prompt, it will print the result, but when I try it in a shell file:

```
output=`timeout 0.5s awk '/FormattedDescription/{getline;print}' archivage001.1.tar` 
echo $output
```

OR execute like this in the prompt:

```
`timeout 0.5s awk '/FormattedDescription/{getline;print}' archivage001.1.tar > output.txt`
```

I will get nothing, is there a way to get the results because I need to operate the result after. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to simply stop scanning the archive as soon as you find the line you want, exit the `awk` command explicitly rather than relying on an arbitrary timeout to kill the command. I suspect you may be running into a buffering issue.

```
output=$( awk '/FormattedDescription/ { getline; print; exit; }' archivage001.1.tar )
```

To grab a bounded set of lines

```
output=$( awk '/PinnInstitutionPath/ {start=1};
               start {print};
               /MountPointList/ {exit}' archivage001.1.tar )
```

Comment: thank you. I understand yout idear, but what i want to get is the lines between /PinnInstitutionPath/ and /MountPointList/ and the number of the line is not fixed, so i tried with your code, "awk '/PinnInstitutionPath/,/MountPointList/{print;exit;}' archivage001.1.tar " ,it just retour one line.

Comment: `awk` doesn't return ranges of lines like that; it applies an action to each line that matches a pattern. You should really put what you are really trying to do in the question.